# How do I make an rightward arrow symbol appear? Right now it's a question mark while using "/u2192"

Tags: java, symbols

I want a rightward arrow symbol and when googling I found several pages saying that writing `"\u2192"` would work. I did not get an error message but in the output there's a question mark instead of the arrow. I am using Java. What could be the issue?

I'm very much a beginner so maybe there's a supersimple solution but I honestly don't even know where to start.

This is basically the code(but with more relevant words than "Words"):

```
System.out.println("Words" + " \t" + "\u2192" + "More words");
```

When I print it I get:

Words     ?More words

What I want is:

Words     *arrow*More words

Comment: Why not directly use something like "->". Just a thought!

Comment: What is your JVM's default character encoding? And does your console support that?

Comment: ([Your code works, at least the way Ideone is configured](https://ideone.com/nKyroU))

Comment: Try configuring your eclipse console to see the output. See [this](http://www.eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/)

Comment: You don't have to concatenate all those string parts. Just put everything in one string.

Answer (score 1):

Characters on computers are represented by *encodings*; Different computer systems use different encodings, and in fact different facilities on the same computer might use different encodings. Encodings represent different characters with different values, so ASCII 'A' is 0x41 (hexadecimal 41), but in EBCDIC it's 0xCA.

So IBM mainframe computers tended to use EBCDIC encoding; older Unix machines tended to use ASCII encodings (of various flavors), and modern systems tend to use Unicode encoding.

In order for any computer program to display your right arrow, it is going to need to understand Unicode encoding. You don't have to worry about it for normal printable characters, because the Java runtime will translate as need be for those -- 'a' in your Java program will be output in ASCII, Unicode, EBCDIC, or whatever the runtime uses. But the right-arrow is not printable, you cannot put it between quote marks (at least not easily), and so the raw binary number is put in the stream. It will work on a system that uses Unicode, but not any other.

I don't know of a right-arrow character in other encodings; one commenter's suggestion to make a right arrow with printable characters seems pretty good to me. But this is why your program, though possibly correct, doesn't produce a right arrow in your output -- whatever is handling your output does not understand the Unicode character.